# GORM mapping causes unit test to fail

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I get a MissingMethodException when running a unit test due to the following line of code

```
class SystemNotification {
    static mapping = {
       read column: 'rd'
    }
    .
    .
}
```

This is the relevant bit of the resulting stacktrace.

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method:
frontlinesms2.SystemNotification.read() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
Possible solutions: read(java.io.Serializable), load(java.io.Serializable), isRead(), create(), getId(), grep()
at frontlinesms2.SystemNotification._clinit__closure1(SystemNotification.groovy:6)
```

Removing the read->rd mapping allows the test to pass. Any thoughts on a way around this issue that does not necessitate removing the code? The domain class is from a plugin, if that's relevant. The plugin runs as a standalone app using h2, but the host application uses MySQL, where "read" is a reserved keyword, which is why we do the mapping to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm so if you want column name change then you have to do following, currently you use read('x') as method:

```
class SystemNotification {
    String read
    static mapping = {
       read column: 'rd'
    }
}
```

And it is correct that test fails.

Comment: My mistake. I typed in the question in haste, but it's actually "read column: 'rd'". I'll edit the question to reflect that.